# Pester and test internal function

Tags: powershell, pester

In my Pester-test I've created a function to Test-SQLConnection.
I can test the function like this:

```
param(
 [string]
 $Server,
 [string]
 $Database

  )

  BeforeAll {
  $testDbServer = $Server
  $testDatabase = $Database

  }

Describe "Status Databaseserver" {
  It "Should login with integrated security" {
  
   Test-SQLConnection "Data Source=$testDbServer; Database=$testDatabase;Integrated 
 Security=True"; | Should -BeTrue 
}
}

function Test-SQLConnection
{    
 [OutputType([bool])]
 Param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                Position=0)]
    $ConnectionString
  )
   try
    {
      $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $ConnectionString;
      $sqlConnection.Open();
      $sqlConnection.Close();

      return $true;
  }
   catch
  {
    return $false;
  }
 }
```

This approach works when I run the test locally on my machine. But when I test from Azure release pipeline I get this error:

```
CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Test-SQLConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The function `Test-SQLConnection`  should be (re)loaded first. Aka,  in the top of your script.

Comment: I put function Test-SQLConnection below the param section and above BeforeAll section, but the error resists.

Comment: What happens when you put it into the `BeforeAll` section?

Comment: That did it! Why is it working inside BeforeAll-section?

Comment: If `Test-SQLConnection` is a function under test (and not a helper function for the test), I would suggest to put it into a module or at least different file and import it at the beginning of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, your function needs to be in the `BeforeAll` block because with Pester v5 and newer Pester now performs a "discovery" phase before executing your tests:

> All code should now be put into It, BeforeAll, BeforeEach, AfterAll,
> or AfterEach. Put no code directly into Describe, Context or on the
> top of your file without wrapping it in one of these blocks (unless
> for good reason).
>
> If code is not put in the proper place, it will run in Discovery, and
> the results will not be available during Run. During the Run phase,
> the internal tree of containers, blocks, and tests are run.

-- https://www.sapien.com/blog/2021/01/20/migrating-from-pester-4-to-pester-5/

I suspect what was occurring for you is that your local machine has an older version of Pester, but when run on Azure DevOps its using the latest.

Comment: Isn't declaring the function under test inside the test nonsense? I would suggest to create a module and import the function under test. Or use a . import. Inside `BeforeAll` I would declare helper functions for testing purposes, but not functions to be tested. Am I wrong? *Edit* I guess it is not clear if it is a helper function or the function under test... You are right about the different pester version in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah I think on this occasion he might be using Pester to do infrastructure testing, rather than testing the function itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think I slightly misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I suspect it actually doesn't "*works when I run the test locally on my machine*" but is *appears* to work on a previous invoked (dot sourced) `Test-SQLConnection` function. In other words: try to open a new PowerShell window on your local machine and confirm it really works or not...

Comment: @MarkWragg was right. On my local machine I've an older version of Pester. That's why it worked locally. I'll remove the old version. Thanks.